# Select data from dropdownlist each time and add them into gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, aspxgridview

suppose that I have a dropdownlist of 20 items and a button beside the dropdownlist(lets name it "Add") and also I have a gridview of empty items at first.

Now what I want to do is that whenever I select an item from dropdownlist and hit the button("Add") the selected item will bind into the gridview.If I select 5 items at 5 times from dropdownlist,5 data will bind to the gridview.I mean each time I select the data from dropdownlist and hit the button the data will bind to the grid view.I want to that in the front end using jquery or javascript

And after adding or binding the data into the gridview I want to save this data into db.

Is it possible using javascript or jquery??

Comment: Refer to this link, it might help you : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c4cfca/how-to-save-data-into-database-using-jquery-and-json-in-asp/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use jQuery to append html to your gridview. When a gridview is rendered, it is just a `<table>`, so adding a new `<tr>` and however many `<td>` you need should work.

`$('#gridView').append("<tr><td>Yourddl.value</td></tr>");`

Comment: can you explain the total process ??